# R magick `image_annotate()` produces `NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition text` error

Tags: r, macos, imagemagick

When trying to add text to an image with the `image_annotate()` function from the `magick` package in R on macOS, I now get an error complaining of `NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition text`.

I have run `brew install ghostscript` and `brew install imagemagick`, both of which report the current versions are installed. What might be causing this error?

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript, x11

# Load a test image
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")

# Attempt to annotate with some text
image_annotate(frink, "frink")
#> Error in magick_image_annotate(image, text, gravity, location, degrees, : R: NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4405

# magick package configuration
str(magick_config())
#> List of 24
#>  $ version           :Class 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
#>   ..$ : int [1:4] 6 9 12 3
#>  $ modules           : logi FALSE
#>  $ cairo             : logi TRUE
#>  $ fontconfig        : logi TRUE
#>  $ freetype          : logi TRUE
#>  $ fftw              : logi FALSE
#>  $ ghostscript       : logi FALSE
#>  $ heic              : logi TRUE
#>  $ jpeg              : logi TRUE
#>  $ lcms              : logi TRUE
#>  $ libopenjp2        : logi TRUE
#>  $ lzma              : logi TRUE
#>  $ pangocairo        : logi TRUE
#>  $ pango             : logi TRUE
#>  $ png               : logi TRUE
#>  $ raw               : logi TRUE
#>  $ rsvg              : logi TRUE
#>  $ tiff              : logi TRUE
#>  $ webp              : logi TRUE
#>  $ wmf               : logi FALSE
#>  $ x11               : logi FALSE
#>  $ xml               : logi TRUE
#>  $ zero-configuration: logi TRUE
#>  $ threads           : int 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       macOS Monterey 12.3
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/London
#>  date     2022-04-18
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli           3.2.0   2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  knitr         1.38    2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magick      * 2.7.3   2021-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.8.3 2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rmarkdown     2.13    2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  styler        1.7.0   2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble        3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue about this on the package GitHub because I was getting the same error. The package author suggested installing xQuartz, and that solved it for me.